# Date constructor throwing exception

Tags: java

```
Date date = new Date(String);
```

This constructor is giving me `Exception`:

The string is `"Wed May 18 02:00:00 AKDT 2016"`.

Comment: That constructor has been deprecated for *19 years*. Avoid deprecated APIs. Use `SimpleDateFormat` (or the `java.time` API, ideally) to parse date/time values.

Comment: Do you mean `java.util.Date`? If so, why are you using deprecated constructor? (Note: `Date date = new Date(String); ` is a [compilable](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WPpycSUtrjjvV7nY) valid code)

Comment: `java.sql.Date` doesn't have such constructor. If `Date` is not `java.util.Date`, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

`new Date(String)` is deprecated, you should use `DateFormat.parse(String)`.
As why your string fails, it is because the timezone (AKDT) is not recognized.

Here's and excerpt from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String)):

> It accepts many syntaxes; in particular, it recognizes the IETF standard date syntax: "Sat, 12 Aug 1995 13:30:00 GMT". It also understands the continental U.S. time-zone abbreviations, but for general use, a time-zone offset should be used: "Sat, 12 Aug 1995 13:30:00 GMT+0430" (4 hours, 30 minutes west of the Greenwich meridian).

And more specifically:

> It also understands the continental U.S. time-zone abbreviations, but for general use, a time-zone offset should be used

So if you insist on using `new Date(String)` you should use:

```
new Date("Wed, May 18 2016 02:00:00 GMT-0800 2016");
```

Notice that the year should be before the time.